# Can we call SAC(Seismic Analysis Code) within AWK?

Tags: awk

I have written a code in the shell...This is a part of my code:-

```
for I in *.SAC

do

SAC<<EOF

LH Delta

q

EOF

p=echo $Delta| awk '{print $1/20}'

r= saclhdr -B $i

echo $p $r

done
```

Can I write this code entirely within AWK???

I want to do that; because for my work, running a shell script is taking much more time than AWK.

Please help me if you can

Comment: I formatted your code for you (see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) but it contains several syntax and other errors so copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it tells you about, then [edit] your question to show your corrected shell script plus sample input/output that demonstrate what you're trying to do and we could test a potential solution against. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: The quick answer to your question is "yes". The more useful answer is "yes, but don't". The right way to speed up your code will depend on whatever your code is supposed to do.